# Find the value stored in this string

Tags: c++11

I am having a string containing the following data:

```
str="AAAEsw==\xfc\x01\xde\x00\x1b\xa41165\xdc\x00\x15\xc0\xc0\xa12\xc0\x01\x00\xef\xa820180518\xa41681&\x00\x0b\x82423\xa42450&\x00\x1c1K\x00\bL\x00#04L\x00\x0f&\x00\x05q131\xa3496K\x00?\xa279L\x00\x04q224\xa3497&\x00?\xa310\xbf\x00\x05\xf5\x16705\xa3599\xdc\x00\x15\xb30.10482180293501049\xa31.0\xa210\x8b\x00\x00\x10\x00\x04\r\x00%\xa11\xb5\x002\xa341\x8f\x00/\xa16\x8e\x00\x04\x81529\xa41938\x8f\x00/\xa14&\x00\x05R18\xa371\xb4\x00$\xa21u\x00\x06\x02\x00\x02q\x00`715\xa371\xb3\x00F\xc0\xc0\xa17\x1e\x00\x03\x02\x00\x02\x97\x01A424\xa2\xd7\x00P\xb40.01\xa9\x01\xf4\x05995475113122\xa40.36\xa263\xcc\x00\x06\x02\x00\x02>\x00r602\xa4117\xfb\x01/\xa21\xb0\x00\x05s705\xa4120\xfc\x00\x0fc\x01\x05\x01\"\x02 02\xb1\x00\x01\x8d\x00\xff\b7584994138335287\xa30.3\xa237\x8c\x00\x05\xf5\x16713\xa3122\xdc\x00\x15\xb20.0995558845299778\xa42.69\xa250S\x01`\xa41.34\xa1\xe1\x00C66\xa11\x0e\x00\x00\x17\x00#14\xb0\x01\x01\xdc\x00 24\x8f\x00O\xc0\xc0\xa26\xdc\x00\x05\x00\xb2\x012233\x8d\x01\x0e\x9c\x00\x04\xb2\x02029\xa1\x9b\x00\xf0\x0b\xb30.07170966331438565\xa41.64\xa2\x8e\x00\x03_\x01\x01\x11\x00\x04\x0e\x00\"\xa13k\x01Q529\xa34\xdf\x00O\xc0\xc0\xa25D\x01\x05b608\xa348?\x023\xa215Q\x00\x06\x02\x00\x02L\x00\x00\x1a\x02#88\x8f\x01\x0f?\x02\x05c516\xa424\xdc\x01\x04\x8e\x00\a\x02\x00\x02K\x00c507\xa368%\x01\x1f2\xd7\x02\x05\x01\x97\x00\x140&\x00\x0f\x8c\x02\x05d601\xa419M\x00\x1f1'\x00\x05P203\xa22\xfc\x03\xf0\n\xb50.0049186530457813096\xa40.\n\x02.19\x8d\x01\x90\xa820180713"
```

how to get the actual value?

Comment: What actual value? If you assign the value " AAA..."  to the string, then that becomes the actual value,

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is currently not very clear. What is the actual value? What have you tried so far to get the actual value? --> Show us your attempts! Cheers :)

Comment: It seems like it is encoded some way, so step one(if I understood what you want correctly) is finding out what form of encoding it has.

Comment: It is encoded using lz4 encoding. How do I decode it in C++ language?